# How to Set interval in GOT http request?

Tags: node.js, time

This will run every time it has found a match in the config.PowerDevices.
I want to place an interval between it so it only checks every 30 seconds.
how can i do that?
I did try multiple things here on the forum but it still triggers every time it has a match.

this is a part of my discord bot.

```
for (var i in config.PowerDevices) {
        
    if (myData.ref == config.PowerDevices[i].ref) {
        var PowerDevicesType = config.PowerDevices[i].type; // type of the device show
        var PowerDevicesName = config.PowerDevices[i].name; // Custom name show
            
        const got = require('got');

        got("http://" + IP.IP + ":" + PORT.PORT + "/JSON?request=getstatus&ref=" + myData.ref)
        .then(response => {
            let content = JSON.parse(response.body);
            console.log("content.Devices[0].status");
        }).catch(console.error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the so-called time-to-live (TTL) design pattern for this. Here's what you do: keep a nextTime object showing the next time each `.PowerDevices` item is ready to check.  Something like this.

```js
const got = require('got');

const howOften = 30000; /* half minute */
if (!global.nextTime) global.nextTime = {}; /* first time initialization */
const now = Date.now();
for (var i in config.PowerDevices) {
  if (myData.ref == config.PowerDevices[i].ref) {
    if (!global.nextTime[i] || global.nextTime[i] < now) {
      /* it's time to check this one. So check it. */
      var PowerDevicesType = config.PowerDevices[i].type; // type of the device show
      var PowerDevicesName = config.PowerDevices[i].name; // Custom name show
      got("http://" + IP.IP + ":" + PORT.PORT + "/JSON?request=getstatus&ref=" + myData.ref)
        .then(response => {
          let content = JSON.parse(response.body);
          console.log("content.Devices[0].status");
          /* set the time-to-live 30s in the future. */
          global.nextTime[i] = now + howOften;
        }).catch(console.error);
    }
    else {
      /* skipped the check on device i: too soon */
    }
  }
}
```

The `global.nextTime` object starts out empty. Then, as you loop over your .`PowerDevices` object you'll check to see whether its entry in `global.nextTime` is absent or if it's before the present time, with this line. If so, it's ready to be checked.

```
  if (!global.nextTime[i] || global.nextTime[i] < now) {
```

Finally, when the check completes you set `global.nextTime[i] = now + howOften` to show when that entry is eligible to be checked again.

Notice that my use of `global.` is not great style. It would be better to put the `nextTime` object in module scope. But you didn't show how your modules are put together, so I went for a global object.

**Pro tip**: Don't put `require()` operations inside loops. It doesn't do any harm but it does slow things down a bit.